# Pandas to nested YAML

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, multi-index

I am trying to build and dump yaml content to file:

Here is what it should look like

```
group:
  Base Configuration:
    id: 1
    group_name: Base Configuration
    group_members:
    - S3-WLP-Kafka-topics-test
    - S3-WLP-BATCH-API-503-P
    group_description: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
  Entity Persistence:
    id: 2
    group_name: Entity Persistence
    group_members:
    - Entity-INPUT-DATA-PERSISTENCE
    - Entity-OUTPUT-DATA-PERSISTENCE
    group_description: Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
  API TESTS:
    id: 3
    group_name: API TESTS
    group_members:
    - API Configuration
    group_description: Standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum
```

My pandas dataframe looks like this:

| id | group_name | group_members | group_description | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Base Configuration | ['S3-WLP-Kafka-topics-test', 'S3-WLP-BATCH-API-503-P'] | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text | group |
| 2 | Entity Persistence | ['Entity-INPUT-DATA-PERSISTENCE', 'Entity-OUTPUT-DATA-PERSISTENCE'] | Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. | group |
| 3 | API TESTS | ['API Configuration'] | Standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum | group |

Here is my attempt to achieve this.

```
        x = self.df_merged['level'].tolist()
        y = self.df_merged['group_name'].tolist()
        z = self.df_merged['id'].tolist()
        a = self.df_merged['group_description'].tolist()
        self.df_merged = self.df_merged.set_index(['level', 'group_name', 'id', 'group_description'])
        self.df_merged = self.df_merged.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(x, y, z, a)))
        nested_dict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
        for keys, value in self.df_merged.group_members.iteritems():
            nested_dict[keys[0]][keys[1]] = value
```

Which gives me:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'group': {'Base Configuration': ['S3-WLP-Kafka-topics-test', 'S3-WLP-BATCH-API-503-P'], 'Entity Persistence': ['Entity-INPUT-DATA-PERSISTENCE', 'Entity-OUTPUT-DATA-PERSISTENCE'], 'API TESTS': ['API Configuration']}})
```

Although this is not exactly what I want and my attempts have been unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is looking for the same, I finally achieved it with `groupby()` and `to_dict()`

```
data = self.df_unchanged.groupby('level')[['group_name', 'id', 'group_description', 'group_members']].apply(
            lambda x: x.set_index('group_name').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()
```

and finally dumping to yaml file:

```
    with open("test.yaml", "w") as yaml_file:
        yaml_file.write(yaml.dump(data, allow_unicode=True, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False))
```